# Angular2 split layout file into header and footer

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am trying to do the multi-layout example in Angular2 described at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-layout-example?file=app%2F_layout%2Fsite-layout%2Fsite-layout.component.html. In my example I have used the Admin LTE template. The problem is that when I split the layout into header and footer, it will have `div` tags opened in the header file and closed the same in footer file. So when I run the application it shows the error

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "div". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag.
```

Here the site layout component have template as

```
<site-header></site-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<site-footer></site-footer>
```

How can we split the files into header and footer? Please help.

Comment: Reproduce it in stackblitz

Comment: @yurzui        I have created it in stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i3xzqv

Comment: Open `site-footer.component.html` I see only `</div>`

Comment: @yurzui        Did you understand my question?

Comment: You can't do this in angular. Template should be correct.

Comment: @yurzui        I want to split the template into header and footer. The tag will be opened in the header and will be closed in the footer. How can I do this?

Comment: `<div><header></header><main></main><footer></footer></div>`

Comment: You can't split tag in angular template